# How to find max in a list of tuples?

Tags: scala

I have the following list of tuples:

```
val arr = List(('a',10),('b',2),('c',3))
```

How to find the tuple with the max key or max value?

The proper answer should be `(c, 3)` for max key lexicographically or `('a', 10)` for max value.

Answer (score 45):

Easy-peasy:

```
scala> val list = List(('a',10),('b',2),('c',3))
list: List[(Char, Int)] = List((a,10), (b,2), (c,3))

scala> val maxByKey = list.maxBy(_._1)
maxByKey: (Char, Int) = (c,3)

scala> val maxByVal = list.maxBy(_._2)
maxByVal: (Char, Int) = (a,10)
```

So basically you can provide to `List[T]` any function `T => B` (where `B` can be any ordered type, such as `Int` or `String` by example) that will be used to find the maximum.

Comment: +1, but it's important to note, I believe, that it'll fail for an empty list. `scala> val list: List[(String, Int)] = Nil
list: List[(String, Int)] = List() | scala> list.maxBy(_._2) | **java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: empty.maxBy**`

Comment: @om-nom-nom if the above list has an extra tuple ('d',10) how do we get both ('a',10),('d',10) as output?

Answer (score 4):

Starting in `Scala 2.13`, a slightly safer solution (which handles empty lists) would consist in using [`maxByOption`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.x/scala/collection/immutable/List.html#maxByOption%5BB%5D(f:A=%3EB)(implicitcmp:scala.math.Ordering%5BB%5D):Option%5BA%5D)/`minByOption` which returns `None` if the sequence is empty:

```
List(('a', 10),('b', 2),('c', 3)).maxByOption(_._1)
// Option[(Char, Int)] = Some((c,3))
List[(Char, Int)]().maxByOption(_._1)
// Option[(Char, Int)] = None
```

This way you could also decide to fallback on a default value when the list is empty:

```
List[(Char, Int)]().maxByOption(_._1).getOrElse(('a', 1))
// (Char, Int) = (a,1)
```

Answer (score 3):

No doubt @[om-nom-nom](https://stackoverflow.com/users/298389/om-nom-nom) provided a concise, correct answer. However, it will throw an exception for an empty list.

**EDIT #2** Given my first edit, it's worthwhile to re-write my original, flawed answer:

```
def max[A](list: List[(A, Int)]): Option[Int] = list match  {
    case Nil => None
    case x :: xs => { val result = xs.foldLeft(x._2) { // acc = first item in list                                        
                              (acc, elem) => if(elem._2 > acc) elem._2 else acc 
                      }
                      Some(result)
                    }
}
```

**Note**: I'm guessing that [scalaz](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz) would let you use a more generic `Num`-like type instead of `Int`, but I haven't worked with it at all.

**Testing**

```
scala> val list = List(('a',10),('b',2),('c',3))
list: List[(Char, Int)] = List((a,10), (b,2), (c,3))

scala> max(list)
res5: Option[Int] = Some(10)

scala> val list: List[(String, Int)] = Nil
list: List[(String, Int)] = List()

scala> max(list)
res6: Option[Int] = None
```

**EDIT** For picking a start value, I decided to edit my answer after talking with @[DustinGetz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/20003/dustin-getz).

Picking `Int.MinValue` might not be a good choice as it's dependent on the particular OS/system on which the app is running.

I would argue that the first element in the list should be the start value. However, there's a potential run-time exception if the list is empty.

Please take a look at this post for more discussion - https://stackoverflow.com/a/23184020/409976.