# Selecting the Minumum Sized List in a List of List

Tags: scala

I have list of list of integers.

```
List(List(1, 1, 1, 1), List(2, 1, 1), List(2, 2))
```

I want to get the minimum sized list from that list which is List(2,2).
What is the recommended way of doing this in Scala  ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Almost duplicate of [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15769366/how-to-find-max-from-a-list-of-tuples-in-scala/15769401#15769401) that was asked today:

```
val xs = List(List(1, 1, 1, 1), List(2, 1, 1), List(2, 2))

xs.minBy(list => list.length)
// res0: List[Int] = List(2, 2)
```