# ReduceLeft with Vector of pairs?

Tags: scala

I have a Vector of Pairs

```
Vector((9,1), (16,2), (21,3), (24,4), (25,5), (24,6), (21,7), (16,8), (9,9), (0,10))
```

and I want to return pair with maximum first element in pair.
I've tried it to do like this:

```
data reduceLeft[(Int, Int)]((y:(Int, Int),z:(Int,Int))=>y._1 max z._1)
```

and

```
data reduceLeft((y:(Int, Int),z:(Int,Int))=>y._1 max z._1)
```

but there is type mismatch error and I can't understand what is wrong with this code.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to find max in a list of tuples?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15769366/how-to-find-max-in-a-list-of-tuples)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why using reduceLeft ?
Just the default max method works very well

```
scala> val v = Vector((9,1), (16,2), (21,3), (24,4), (25,5), (24,6), (21,7), (16,8), (9,9), (0,10))
v: scala.collection.immutable.Vector[(Int, Int)] = Vector((9,1), (16,2), (21,3), (24,4), (25,5), (24,6), (21,7), (16,8), (9,9), (0,10))

scala> v.max 
res1: (Int, Int) = (25,5)
```

If you want reduceLeft instead :

```
v.reduceLeft( (x, y) => if (x._1 >= y._1) x else y )
```

Your error is you have to return a tuple, not an int

```
y._1 max z._1
```

The max function here on two int return an int.

Answer (score 0):

`max` works great in this example. However, if you are wondering how to do this using `reduceLeft` here it is:

```
val v = Vector((9,1), (16,2), (21,3), (24,4), (25,5), (24,6), (21,7), (16,8), (9,9), (0,10))
v.reduceLeft( ( x:(Int, Int), y:(Int,Int) ) => if(y._1 > x._1) y else x)
```