# ReduceByKey on specified value element

Tags: scala, apache-spark

New to Spark and trying to understand `reduceByKey`, which is designated to accept RDD[(K, V)]. What isn't clear to me is *how* to apply this function when the value is a list/tuple...

After various mapping and filtering operations my RDD has ended up in the form of `(Cluster:String, (Unique_ID:String, Count:Int))`, in which I can have many elements belonging to the same cluster, e.g.:

```
 Array((a,(lkn,12)), (a,(hdha,2)), (a,(naa,35)), (b, (cdas,20)) ...)
```

Now I want to use `reduceByKey` to find, for each cluster the element with the highest count (so one entry per cluster). In the above example this would be`(a,(naa,35))` for cluster `a`.

I can figure out how to find the maximum per cluster if I have a simple (key, value) pair with `reduceByKey` and `math.max`. But I don't understand how to extend this when value represents a list/tuple of values.

Am I using the wrong function here?

Comment: Can you just use maxBy like in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15769366/how-to-find-max-in-a-list-of-tuples ?

Comment: @C4stor they are working with an `RDD` which does not have a `maxBy`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can:

```
rdd.reduceByKey { case (x, y) => if (x._2 > y._2) x else y }
```

This:

- logically partitions data into groups defined by the key (`_._1`)

  - Keys for "a": `(a, [(lkn,12), (hdha,2), (naa,35), ...])`
  - Keys for "b": `(b, [(cdas,20), ...])`
- reduces values in each group by comparing second element of values (`(x._2 > y._2)`) and returns one with the higher number.

Comment: OP seems to be confused by the general mechanics of `reduceBy` and how to use lamdas on collections -- it might be useful to explain your code snippet or provide a resource explaining how it works

Comment: Thank you, I think I get it now.

Comment: @LostInOverflow looks great